# docker-compose cannot start service: "exec: \"python3\": executable file not found

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

(I'm not deeply experienced with `docker`, fwiw)

I have a django appication I'm containerizing. Currently when I run 
`docker-compose up` the `redis` service starts up, but `api`exits with error: `ERROR: for api  Cannot start service api: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:296: starting container process caused "exec: \"python3\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown`

```
#docker-compose.yaml

version: '3'
services:
  redis:
      image: redis
      ports:
        - 6379
  api:
      build:
        context: ../backend/
        dockerfile: ../backend/Dockerfile
      env_file: .env
      volumes:
          - ../backend:/code/
      ports:
        - "8001:8001"
     depends_on:
        - redis
```

with

```
#../backend/Dockerfile
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
ADD . /code/
WORKDIR /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD python manage.py runserver
```

and

```
#./.env 

DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=backend.settings.dev
DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=<redacted>
SENTRY_URL=<redacted>
```

I've also, based on other issues, tried using both `CMD` and `RUN` with their differing argument types, i.e. in the existing shell and without, but the output hasn't changed.

I should also acknowledge that it's possible I'm not restarting actually catching the updates to `docker-compose.yaml` or `Dockerfile`. My workflow has been `$ docker-compose down` followed by `$ docker-compose up`.

EDITS:

@henrik-andersson pointed me in the right direction. The proximate cause of the error is the fact that the image itself was not built, so the executable `python` didn't exist. the command I needed to run was `docker-compose up --build`

Comment: Have you built the images properly?

Comment: i don't know--how would I check?

Comment: Try `docker-compose up --build`

Comment: thanks, see edits for the result. I'll accept yer answer if you care to

Answer (score 0):

`docker-compose up --build` showed that the images were not built. This was fixed by moving the `docker-compose.yaml` file to the parent directory s.t. the `Dockerfile` for each service could be accessed properly